# Trigger android ringer from Pebble watchFACE not watchAPP

Tags: android, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, pebble-js

I have a watchface built for a medical app , it vibrates the watch for certain alarms based on data received from the server . I would like to be able to trigger phone ringer (for alarms) without a companion android app . Is there any possibility to get around with it ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to interact with the phone from the watch (beyond the basics like fetching data from the web and getting location) is to use a companion app for the phone.

Comment: I am not an android programmer , but I have a way with phonegap/cordova. I found this plugin https://github.com/jbeuckm/cordova-plugin-pebble , do you think this can help to make a companion app which receives messages from pebble app and then trigger android ringer using cordova ?